# Need to group by and get aggregate and grand total according to search parameter

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, cumulative-sum

I am using SQL 2005.  I have some data from an old application that did not follow the rules for normalization.  The table is for Invoices, and the table allows for 13 purchase items per record.  So in each row of my table I have a non-unique integer field itemID, itemID1, itemID2 ... itemID12.  For each itemID I also have "lbs_total" and "line_total" - so itemID, lbs_total, line_total ... itemID1, lbs_total1, line_total1 ... etc.  It's a mess, I know.

Each row has a unique Customer Number ("cno") and an Invoice Date ("inv_date").  My proc needs to allow for params for the item number, which could exist in any of the fields for item, and a start date and end date for BETWEEN on the inv_date.

I also need to get the aggregate for the lbs_total and the line_total according to each cno.

I also need a grand total on the lbs_total and line_total.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error?   Please post the query you are trying to use.

Comment: I was able to find a solution.  [solution_here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/80a6fabe-0aa8-43d4-96f6-433b9c728627/how-to-group-by-and-get-aggregate-where-a-certain-condition-is-true?forum=transactsql#b9991143-2b91-430e-b65e-de27ac983f4b)